# Argument in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop, arguments

Pls help me im stuck

```
def printdata(something):
    for i in something + "_raw":
        something + "_raw_names" = i.findAll("div",{"itemprop":"name"})
        something + "_name" = something + "_raw_names"[0].text
        print("Name: " + something + "_name")
```

I want that printdata(bodies) is doing this:

```
for i in bodies_raw:
    bodies_raw_names = i.findAll("div",{"itemprop":"name"})
    bodies_name = bodies_raw_names[0].text
    print("Name: " + bodies_name)
```

If u have a solution pls tell me because im struggling with this way too long

Comment: Its impossible the way you are trying to approach it ! You cannot modify the `variable's` name at runtime. I would suggest to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want - you have shared two functions that look similar. What's going wrong?

Comment: @doctorlove: the OP is trying to construct a variable name by appending a string to it, i.e. `bodies + "_raw"` to give `bodies_raw`.  Yes, I know.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem please publish an answer to your own question down below,  but don't edit your original post by removing the initial question.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't try and create / access / modify variable names dynamically like that. If you have a lot of similarly named variables, consider storing them in a dict. e.g:

```
raws = {'bodies': bodies_raw, 'other': other_raw}
```

and then your function can be:

```
def printdata(something):
    for i in raws[something]:
        raw_names = i.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "name"})
        raw_name = raw_names[0].text
        print("Name: " + raw_name)
```